# How to add ionic list item while scrolling the ion-scroll

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created the ion-list with specific collection and created the scrollbar for this list item using ion-scroll. I want add the some list item dynamically while scrolling the scrollbar. I have used below code.

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>Scroll X and Y</title>
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ion-view title="Home" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" on-scroll="scroll()" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <ion-list style="width: 100%">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);
    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            //var 
            $scope.items.push(i);
        }
        var n = 100;
        $scope.scroll = function ()
        {
             for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                $scope.items.push(n);
                n++;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have tried above code but scrolling is not smooth. So please suggest any other way to append the list item.

Comment: Please don't create html in your angular code. Instead create the array there, and put the dynamic html in your html. Also, you don't state what doesn't work, can you elaborate

Comment: @devqon I tried the mentioned code, but while scrolling the list it's not smooth. suggest any other way to append list item.

Comment: Please explain 'is not smooth'

Comment: @devqon it's not scrolling fastly as like native scroll of ionic. Scrolling is slow or get some lag. Due to $scope.$apply().

Comment: Then remove `$scope.$apply()`. I can imagine that the native scroll already happens in the angular's digest cycle, so no need to apply manually

Comment: @devqon While i removing the $scope.$apply() the newly inserted list items are not added.

Comment: Then try putting the complete `for` loop **in** the `$scope.$apply(cb)` callback: `$scope.$apply(function(){ //for-loop });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123854/discussion-between-balachandar-and-devqon).